# Error while Listing scanned Bluetooth Low Energy Device

Tags: android

I am developing an android application which scans and displays the Bluetooth Low Energy devices in a ListView. My problem is I am able to display only one item in the ListView even if there are many Ble devices.I am using ArrayList and ArrayAdapter which is very essential.Below is part of my code, can anyone tell me what is my error and how I can overcome it.

```
public class ScanList extends Activity {
public  ListView scanDeviceList;
private  BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private  Handler mHandler;
private  ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice> adapter1;
Context context;
Activity activity;
public  ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> devices;
public String mDeviceAddress,mDeviceName;
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
// Stops scanning after 10 seconds.
private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.scanned_device);
    scanDeviceList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.scanDeviceList);
    mHandler = new Handler();
    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }


    scanLeDevice(true);
}

public  void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
    if (enable) {
        // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mScanning = false;
                mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);
        mScanning = true;
        mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    } else {
        mScanning = false;
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    }
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

public  BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
        new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        devices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
                        devices.add(device);
                        adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice>(scanDeviceList.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,devices);
                        scanDeviceList.setAdapter(adapter1);


                    }

                });

            }


        };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time scan , onLeScan only return 1 item (although many becons advertising)

```
devices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

public  BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
        new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        devices.add(device);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: this is same as what i am doing right? how does it differ?

Comment: sorry Phuoc Huynh your answer is correct. At first i thought it was same as mine but when implemented with some changes gave me my expected results. thank you friend it helped me a lot.